# 2D-subtract 3D objects, to make background visible?

Tags: canvas, webgl, augmented-reality, three.js

For an AR type application, I would like to know:

> Is it possible to *2D-subtract* one WebGL 3D rendering from another, to make the background show through?

Example, as of 2012-07-22 CEST implemented purely with 2D canvas: [Reality Builder](http://www.RealityBuilder.com) ([source](http://code.google.com/p/realitybuilder))

Note that you can move the red block *behind* blocks shown in the photo. This is done as follows:

1. The red block is drawn.
2. `globalCompositeOperation` is set to `destination-out`.
3. Blocks are drawn in the exact same positions as the blocks in the photo that are in front of the red block. Thereby they are subtracted from the red block.

Comment: The link doesn't load here... :/

Comment: It's hosted on Nodejitsu, the nameservers of which are [currently getting DDOSed](https://twitter.com/zerigo/status/227262239407759360).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do some trickiness if you set the `material.opacity` of the blocker object to `0` and render it first.

Comment: It works! I just modified the example from the [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) [README.md](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/6492798b46033c8b35c9d2d5cbe7251ffbcb8d89/README.md) (r49) by changing the renderer to WebGL, setting `Wireframe` to `false` and adding a second cube with `opacity: 0` to the scene (*after* the first cube, though). The part of the second cube that is in front of the first cube then gets subtracted, letting a background image show through.